# Database solution for large infrequently-accessed data sets

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

We use MongoDB to store daily logs of statistics about 10s of thousands of items in our database--the collection is currently approaching 100 million records.  This data is useful for data mining, but is accessed infrequently.  We recently moved it from our main MySQL database to a Mongo database; this turned out not to be ideal--Mongo is optimized for fast reads, keeping all of its indexes in memory, and the index on this table is very large.

What is a good way to store large amounts of data for daily large writes, but infrequent reads?  We are considering a separate MySQL installation on a separate system.  Another possibility might be a NoSQL solution that did not require an index kept in memory.

Comment: Have you already utilized the Archive storage engine in mysql?  It is intended directly for seldom referenced data.
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html

Comment: "What is a good way to store large amounts of data for daily large writes," - a database server, with good hardware and correctly setup

Comment: Consider moving the old(er) data to an OLAP warehouse (even if it's just another MySQL elsewhere) using some ETL tooling, perhaps. This may also influence (or be influenced by) any data-retiring or shaping that should occur, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, a nosql is good for fast reads of simple data. Since will need to query and possibly do relational operations on this data, I'd recommend a separate mysql installation for this.

You will want to minimize the sql indexes for fast writes.

Comment: Depends on which "nosql" implementation is being talked about.